# Getting a user ID on a login page

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, authentication

How can I pass a user ID from my login page to an end page to allow the user access to my application? I want to make a application like Yahoo; if we open a Yahoo page, and enter our user name and password for login, then wherever we go we don't have any problem. If we want to update our profile we can do so easily. I want the same for my iPhone application; the user logs in and I can then use the ID throughout my application, and if the user wants to update, then he can easily update values in the server's database.

Comment: It's amazing what a little punctuation can do. I cannot manage to read your run-on paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are aware about application delegate than you can do it like, Declare one variable let say user id is integer than as follows.

```
@interface YourAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    LenseCareViewController *viewController;
    NSInteger intUserID;
}
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) NSInteger intUserID; //Synthesize this variable in implementation

//Your Header File 
#import "YourAppDelegate.h"

@interface YourViewController : UIViewController
{
    YourAppDelegate *appDelegate;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) YourAppDelegate *appDelegate;

@end

//Your Implementation file
@implementation YourViewController
@synthesize appDelegate

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.appDelegate.intUserID = 5; //Assign value to this variable and you can have access globally.
}

@end
```

Hope it helps. If any doubts please leave a comment.

Comment: @Jennis...ya you are right ,he can use the appdelegate for that and pass the userinfo to that and then can access in anyviewcontroller.


+1 for you.....for helping this guy in the right direction.Even he can adopt another ways but i think that would be tedious for him.He should then go with this.

Comment: @Rocky I don't understand what your problem exactly, can you please elaborate.

Comment: @Jennis My pleasure dear......you were right so i voted you up.....Now cheers to both of us

Comment: @Rocky Than this way you can share TokenID through out the application. Declare ApplicationDelegate in all of your view controller where you want to use this TokenID. This is the simplest way to share information between controllers. And when user is logging out set this TokenID to nil.

Comment: @Jennis could you please tell me how to do this because in my JSON response contains Results array and TokeniD is outside the array

Answer (score 0):

The best way  would be  to store the credentials details in keychain. It is automatically encrypted and backed up. Refer the [Keychain Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1) and [Keychain Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000898) for more help.